# How to write array values into a csv file in PHP?

Tags: php, file, fopen, fwrite

I have an array whose structure is like  `$data = array{0=>'abc',1=>xyz,2=>tqs}`

Now I need to write these values into a csv file. I need to display every value in 1st column and with everytime new row on new insert along with previous value already available.

Below is the code I am using but everytime I execute it I get the last value in the file:

```
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
      echo $data[$c];
   echo  $query = "select prod_sku,prod_name 
    from
      tbl_product
    where 
     prod_sku = '".$data[$c]."'";
     $result = mysql_query($query);
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     if(empty($row)){
     print_r($row);
     echo 'test';
     $fp = fopen("file.csv", "w");
     print_r($data[0]);

      fputcsv($fp, $data[0]);
      fclose($fp);


  }
```

How can i achieve this using PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing `fopen` inside the for loop, so every time the loop runs, your file gets re-written. Move the `fopen` and `fclose` outside of the loop and it will work. Like this;

```
$fp = fopen("file.csv", "w");
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++)
{
     $query = "select prod_sku,prod_name from tbl_product where prod_sku = '".$data[$c]."'";
     $result = mysql_query($query);
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

     fputcsv($fp, $data);
} 
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL you could use `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`:

```
SELECT prod_sku, prod_name
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/products.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM tbl_product
WHERE 1
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html